# How to resolve app not found issue while in android studio?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I'm working on android studio. When I run my app through device, after selecting application the system showing toast "App not found".

When I use search bar to search and open app it works perfectly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

it might be Gradle issue or you have some error with your XML file.
you can check-in your logs for more specific.

Comment: logcat result - Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe

Comment: you can toggle the log view to see the error in details.
refer : (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J-R880yiKj5F8w2u-_OBabPn2fQtzPqT)